# Mongodb server selection time out with nginx, nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nginx

I struggled https setting on my web application. And It looks like I've succeeded.

But, There was problem when mongodb connection with nodejs.

I guess nginx https reverse proxy setting cause this trouble but,
I don't know where and how to approach.

I should be very grateful to you if you might help me.

#### Environment

- Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- Nginx 1.14.0
- Mongdb 4.2.3
- NodeJS + Koa
- AWS EC2

#### Problem

Mongodb return below error when trying connection

- Error message from nodejs

  > Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
- Error message from nginx

  > [error] 14495#14495: *230328 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 210.218.178.27, server: songistock.net, request: "GET /GetGroupPrice?target=UNION&dateOpt=2019-12-10 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/GetGroupPrice?target=UNION&dateOpt=2019-12-10", host: "www.songistock.net", referrer: "https://www.songistock.net/"

#### I tried

- Setting Upstream in nginx
- Rebooted Ubuntu
- Reinstalled Nginx, Mogodb

#### Setting & Code

- /etc/nginx/sites-available

```
upstream stream_mongo_backend {
   server localhost:27017;
}

server {
   listen 27017;

   location / {
      proxy_pass http://stream_mongo_backend;
   }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
 listen 443 ssl;
 server_name songistock.net www.songistock.net;

 ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.songistock.net/fullchain.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.songistock.net/privkey.pem;

 ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
 ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
 location / {
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;

         proxy_set_header        Host $host;
         proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_read_timeout      120;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

- NodeJS Code

This code working with https setting

```js
const Router = require('koa-router');
const router = new Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const winston = require('../logger/winston');

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.once('open', function () {
    winston.info("db connected");
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/songi_stock', 
{ useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

If need more information. Please comment. then I will add more information. 
I really want to solve this problem.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because `nginx` is mainly an HTTP server so when you redirect to Mongo it tries to use the `http` protocol yet Mongo expects a raw `TCP` connection. You should try wrapping your `server` and `upstream` blocks for Mongo with a `stream` block.

EDIT: `stream` needs to be on he same level as the `http` block. You can also make include for `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf` outside of `http` block.

```
http{}
stream {

upstream stream_mongo_backend {
   server localhost:27017;
   }

server {
   listen 27017;

   location / {
      proxy_pass http://stream_mongo_backend;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but when I tried it's not working. nginx said "stream" directive is not allowed

Comment: Thank you for edit. I just tried your edited way but now nginx said "location" directive is not allowed

Comment: did you put the `include` outside of the `http` block or you only put `stream` outside of it? Try both ways.

Comment: Thank you!! @C.Gochev I solved problem with your EDIT answer and restarted mongodb service. EDIT was right. Mongodb died while testing your answer. So look likes faild.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution:

You need not work on multiple .conf files. There is Dockerfile that need to be created in app.js or index.js running directory.

Using docker, build server and assign multiple port to localhost as forward proxy.

```
user root;
worker_processes auto;
pid/run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;


events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}
 
http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    upstream backend{
      server  http://127.0.0.1:11111;
      server  http://127.0.0.1:22222;
      server  http://127.0.0.1:33333;
      server  http://127.0.0.1:44444;
    }

    server{
       listen 80;
       server_name conspeer.in;
       root /conspeer_new;

       rewrite ^/(./$) /$1;

       location / {
           proxy_pass http://backend/;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      }
    }

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
   
    gzip on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;

   }
```